# SP 2010: Collect Feedback Workflow - Word Doc Doesn't Open

Tags: workflow

I've created a Collect Feedback workflow using the default template included with SharePoint 2010.

My library contains a Word doc created with Office 2010 and Track Changes has been enabled on the document.

After initiating the workflow, I receive the usual email. When I click the 'Open this task...' button, my document does not open. Only the form to add comments opens up.

There is a link to the document in the email's body, but clicking it simply downloads a copy of the document. Opening it does not display the typical message bars.

Any help is appreciated!